# Accessibility for Vectors of Singly Linked Lists (or possibly a Linked List of Linked Lists)

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

Been wracking my mind all day trying to hammer out the underlying data structures for a challenge assignment in one of my programming classes.

The problem is as follows:

Given an assortment of objects (each of which includes an identifier and a weight) and a supply of containers (which have a fixed weight capacity), pack all the items using as few containers as possible without overloading any of them.

I have the logic aspects hammered out using a hodgepodge of arrays, but the dynamic nature of this assignment has me wanting to optimize things by using vectors and/or linked lists.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    int number;
    double weight;

    bool operator < (const Item& str) const
    {
        return (weight < str.weight);
    }
};

class Node
{
    int number;
    double weight;
    Node* next;

  public:
    Node()
    {};

    void SetID(int iNum)
    {
        number = iNum;
    };

    void SetWeight(double iWeight)
    {
        weight = iWeight;
    };

    void SetNext(Node* iNext)
    {
        next = iNext;
    }

    int GetID()
    {
        return number;
    };

    double GetWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    };

    Node* Next()
    {
        return next;
    };
};

class List
{
    Node* head;
    double weight;

  public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        weight = 0;
    };

    int Size()
    {
        Node* tmp;
        int count = 0;
        for (tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->Next())
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    };

    double Weight()
    {
        return weight;
    }; 

    void Print()
    {
        Node *tmp = head;
        if ( tmp == NULL )
        {
            cout << "   E M P T Y" << endl;
            return;
        }

        do
        {
            cout << setw(8) << tmp->GetID() << "  |  " << setw(8) << tmp->GetWeight() << endl;
            tmp = tmp->Next();
        } while ( tmp != NULL );
    };

    void Append(int iNum, double iWeight)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->SetID(iNum);
        newNode->SetWeight(iWeight);
        newNode->SetNext(NULL);

        Node *tmp = head;
        if ( tmp != NULL )
        {
            while ( tmp->Next() != NULL )
            {
                tmp = tmp->Next();
            }
            tmp->SetNext(newNode);
        }
        else
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        weight += iWeight;
    };
};

double ItemWeights(vector<Item> iVect) 
{
    double total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < iVect.size(); i++)
    {
        total += iVect[i].weight;
    }
    return total;
}


int main()
{
    const double MAX_WEIGHT = 20;
    vector< Item > source;
    //
    //  Segment of code which propagates the vector data
    //  works fine, but is excluded for the sake of brevity
    //  
    double totalWeight = ItemWeights(source);

    //  Duplicate vector of items
    vector< Item > items(source);

    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << setw(8) << items[i].number << setw(8) << items[i].weight << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n Total weight = " << totalWeight << endl;
    cout << "\n\n Press any key to continue... ";
    getch();

//  Solution A-Original
//  vector< vector< Item > > boxesAO( vector< Item >);
//  boxesAO[0].push_back({items[items.size()].number, items[items.size()].weight});

    vector< List > boxesAO;

//  boxesAO[0].Append(items[items.size()].number, items[items.size()].weight);


    return 0;
}
```

I've left some of the methods I've tried in the code (commented out) - none of which worked.  As I mentioned above, I've got it working with arrays of linked lists and with 2D arrays, but the vast range of potential input makes these problematic at best.  Either a bunch of empty lists taking up space or, worse, not having enough.

I'm thinking that vector< List > is my best option, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to access any of the List functionality.

If someone would be so helpful as to offer a suggestion for how to create a "dynamic 2D array" as well as a code example of how to access it, I would be most greatly appreciative.  My deepest thanks in advance.

EDIT:

@jaredad7 ~ That's what I've been trying, but it keeps causing the program to crash.

```
List box;
box.Append(items[items.size()].number, items[items.size()].weight);
```

This works just fine - no problems whatsoever.

The earlier code propagates a 1D vector of Item structs, which also works properly.

```
vector< List > boxes;
boxes[0].Append(items[items.size()].number, items[items.size()].weight);
```

This compiles fine but crashes during execution, no matter what index is used.  (I'm also using couts for debugging, and the issue most definitely lies with trying to access the List functions.)

I'm suspecting that .push_back or somesuch may be needed, but I haven't been able to find much information concerning vectors of List objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, my first suggestion would be to go with the vector (if that is allowed). As for accessing functions/attributes of a member of a vector, it's done the same way as an array, that is:

```
vectorname[i].functionname(a,b,c);
```

The best way to do this without vectors would be to use your nodes as the item container (a struct), and handle node-creation, deletion, etc. in your list class. Then, you would only really need one container for as many objects of one type as you need. You can make the type dynamic (although it appears you only need doubles for this project) by adding a class template (use google if you are unfamiliar with templates in C++). This will allow your user to make a container for each type of data (much like a vector).